# How to replace OrderBy from linq.dynamic with OrderBy from regular linq?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a database table Notepad that has two columns for simplicity (id, text). I'm displaying the result of my query in a DataGridView. What I'm trying to do is when user clicks on either headers, the data will be sorted based on the header text.

I was able to achieve that using Linq.Dynamic OrderBy as shown below.

```
  private void dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if (sortAscending)
     {
        notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notes.OrderBy(notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName).ToList();
        notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
     }
     else
     {
        notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notes.OrderBy(notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName).Reverse().ToList();
        notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
     }

     sortAscending = !sortAscending;
  }
```

I want to replace this with regular OrderBy from System.Linq. The problem is this function takes a lambda expression and it will make the code lengthy if used like this and not maintainable if we have 20 columns to sort.

```
  private void dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if (sortAscending)
     {
        if (notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "id")
        {
           notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notes.OrderBy(note => note.Id).ToList();
           notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else if (notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "text")
        {
           notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notes.OrderBy(note => note.Text).ToList();
           notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }


     }
     else
     {
        //Sort descending
     }

     sortAscending = !sortAscending;
  }
```

I appreciate any feedback

//Edit

//This will query the database table Note
`List<Note> notes = nodteLogic.GetNotes();`

The Note object has two properties Id and Text
Then what I do is the following

```
notepadBindingSource.DataSource = notes;
notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notepadBindingSource;
```

The dataGrid will be populated with the list values

Comment: Isn't the DataGridView doing exactly that on its own when you click a Column Header (unless you set a `Column.SortMode = NotSortable`)? Then, if you need to sort the data *manually*, you can use the `DataTable.DefaultView.Sort` property. Is there a reason why you're trying to override the default behavior with a custom one that does the same thing?

Comment: I don't have the columns explicitly added to the dataGrid, I'm adding the columns based on what the list of nodes has, therefore, I can't set the Column.SortMode

Comment: You don't need to set it. The default is `Automatic`. What is a *list of nodes*? Don't you *have a database table Notepad*? Do you mean you have loaded the data, from a database, to a `List<OfSomething>` that is not sortable? Can you give some more context to the question and a better description of the objects you're working with?

Comment: The "regular" linq's OrderBy expects a `Func<T, TKey>`, without a non-generic version. This means that even if you make a lambda generator, `static Func<Note, T> GenerateLambda<T>(string property_name)` (which is easy to do), you will have to call it as `OrderBy(GenerateLambda<int>("int_property"))` or `OrderBy(GenerateLambda<string>("string_property"))`, which again will require a manual switch, this time over the type of the property (`int`, `string`), not the name.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use regular linq like this, Thank you for all the help.

```
  private void dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
  {

     if (sortAscending)
     {
        notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notes.OrderBy(note => note.GetType().GetProperty(notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName)
                                                        .GetValue(note, null)).ToList();
        notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
     }
     else
     {
        notepadDataGridView.DataSource = notes.OrderBy(note => note.GetType().GetProperty(notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName)
                                                        .GetValue(note, null)).Reverse().ToList();
        notepadDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
     }

     sortAscending = !sortAscending;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things with the contents of your DataGridView it is better to separate the contents from the way that it is displayed. In WPF this is standard, in WinForms this is encouraged using a `BindingList<T>`

Is is not difficult to create a sortable NotesBindingList, derived from `BindingList<Note>`. You'll have to enable sorting, and override the sort methods.

It is even easier if you use Nuget package [Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView).

This BindingListView gives you automatic sorting by clicking on the column header, in the correct direction.

```
List<Note> notes = GetNotes();
BindingListView<Note> viewNotes = new BindingListView<Note>(notes);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = viewNotes;
```

This is enough to show your notes. If you click on the header of a column, the notes will be sorted in the correct order, using default IComparer. The glyphs in the column headers are updated automatically.

If you want a non standard sort order, you'll have to provide an IComparer and call `ApplySort(IComparer<T> comparer);`